# How to underline a word in Vim?

Tags: vim

I want to underline a word in Vim. How can I do this?

After closing the file and reopening it that word should still be underlined.

Comment: Vim isn't a word processor. The files it edits are plain text.

Comment: You may find this answer helpful:
http://superuser.com/a/827369/380406

Comment: A similar question is answered here:
http://superuser.com/a/827369/380406

Answer (score 6):

Bearing in mind that Vim is a (some might say *the*) **text** editor and not a word processor, there are two ways this can be addressed.

### Updating the file

Assuming that you want to edit the text file to underline a heading or similar. You can do this by duplicating the line using <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (or [**`:t .<CR>`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:t)) and replacing the text with hyphens with a [**`:substitute`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute) command like `:s!\S!-!g`.

Of course you will need to [**`:write`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#:write) this file to preserve these.

### Formatting the display

Alternatively, you can use the `:match` functionality to underline the text in your editor without touching the file:

```
:match Underlined /someword\|otherword/
```

You would need to add this to a startup script (such as [**`vimrc`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc)) to persist this formatting.

See [**`:help :match`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#:match) in Vim for more information.

Comment: it's ok .... after close and reopen the word is not underlined

Comment: You could add the match command to a `filetype` or `syntax` plugin. (See `:help plugin` in Vim). As a hack you could add it to your `.vimrc` (or `_vimrc` on Windows).

Comment: The :match command given is limited to underlining specific words that you define in the match command.  A more general purpose method might be to match words that are written between underscores. For example, any word or phrase written between two underscores would be underlined by the command:
":match /_.*_/"   Again, you would have to put the command in .vimrc (or somewhere else) to have it always work in all your files.  Also, the particular example given using underscores may not be perfect, but it illustrates the idea.

Comment: @Herbert: Good idea. A non-greedy match might be more useful, though. Something like `:match /_[^_]\{-}_/` (untested)

Comment: You also can use the diagraph: insert mode: `<C-k>'-` result: `‾` Though still using two lines.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article [Underline using dashes automatically](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Underline_using_dashes_automatically) that describes one way to underline when writing plain text files.

Comment: It's underlining hole line. I don't want to underline hole line 


eg: this is sample line // underline sample only

Comment: You also can use the diagraph: insert mode: `<C-k>'-` result: `‾` Though still using two lines.